# Integrate WCF service with Outsystems

Tags: vb.net, wcf, soap, svc, outsystems

How to integrate WCF service with Outsystems? (instead of web service)

- The address of the WCF service: **http://servername/Services/Service.svc**

I tried this link but it cant make it.(https://success.outsystems.com/documentation/how_to_guides/integrations/how_to_consume_a_web_service_in_integration_studio/)

I also tried this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pvzPX5cMjo4
But, it return an error messages as below:

(SOAP Web Service unsupported by WCF. Consider sharing the following error details with the service provider to check the service compatibility with WCF. (Detail: The type or namespace name 'schema' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)))

Comment: perhaps this might be more appropriate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/accessing-services-using-a-wcf-client

Comment: Does your wcf service work properly before migration? Please share a few details of the code.